# Is it always true that $H^0(X)\cong\ \widetilde{H}^0(X)\oplus\mathbb{Z}?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

It does follow from $\widetilde{H}^0(X)\cong Hom(\widetilde{H}_0(X),\mathbb{Z})$ and the fact that it's true for homologies and $Hom(\mathbb{Z}^n,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^n,$ right?
I am just confused that this property is always noted for homologies, but I've never seen it written out for cohomologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon:X\rightarrow\ast$ be the collapse map onto the 1-point space. Then

$$\widetilde H^n(X)=coker(H^n(\ast)\xrightarrow{\epsilon^*} H^n(X)).$$

If $X$ is nonempty, then it has a point $x$, and this defines a map $x:\ast\rightarrow X$ satisfying $\epsilon \circ x=id_\ast$. It follows from functorality that $\epsilon^*$ is split injective in this case, and in particular
$$H^n(X)\cong \widetilde H^n(X)\oplus H^n(\ast)\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
If $X$ is empty, then people often *define* its reduced homology to be $\mathbb{Z}$, so the answer to your question is affirmitive even in this case, but I mean what are you even doing with your life at this stage?

Comment: You mean for $n=0,$ right? 
Btw, about empty set. Doesn't it follow from the augmented chain complex that $\widetilde{H}_{-1}(\emptyset)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\widetilde{H}_{k}(\emptyset)=0$ for $k>0?$ And same from cohomologies.

Comment: @Haldot the argument I gave clearly works for all $n$, and any generalised cohomology theory. If you are using ordinary homology, then $H^n(\ast)=0$ if $n\neq 0$ and $H^n(X)=0$ for $n<0$, so there isn't much happening if $n\neq 0$. The argument you gave for $\widetilde H^*(\emptyset)$ is correct, and what I was referring to.